# How would I scale an SVG line while retaining its midXmidY position

Tags: svg

I have a simple 2-node graph:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="400" width="400">
<circle cx='100' cy='100' r='20' fill='none'
stroke='black'/>
<circle cx='300' cy='100' r='20' fill='none'
stroke='black'/>

<line x1='100' y1='100' x2='300' y2='100' stroke='black' transform='scale(1)'/>
</svg>
```

Would it be possible to use scale to make the line (i.e., the edge) so that the line does not go into the circles (as per the SVG below):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="400" width="400">
<circle cx='100' cy='100' r='20' fill='none'
stroke='black'/>
<circle cx='300' cy='100' r='20' fill='none'
stroke='black'/>

<line x1='120' y1='100' x2='280' y2='100' stroke='black'/>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translate so the line's centre is at the origin. Scale the line. Translate the line back to its original position.

The original line length is 200. It needs to become 200 - 2r = 200 - 40 = 160.

160 / 200 = 0.8 so that's the scale we need to apply.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="400" width="400">
<circle cx='100' cy='100' r='20' fill='none'
stroke='black'/>
<circle cx='300' cy='100' r='20' fill='none'
stroke='black'/>

<line x1='100' y1='100' x2='300' y2='100' stroke='black' transform='translate(200,100)scale(0.8)translate(-200,-100)'/>
</svg>
```